# Questions on std::distance and std::istream_iterator

Tags: c++

What does [Network.cpp](https://github.com/leela-zero/leela-zero/blob/next/src/Network.cpp#L246-L247) do ?

```
auto count = std::distance(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(iss), std::istream_iterator<std::string>());
```

Note: wtfile could be found at [Best Network Hash](http://zero.sjeng.org/) and the following piece of code returns *count* as 256 for the latest hash file (#236). Why ?

```
// First line was the version number
auto linecount = size_t{1};
auto channels = 0;
auto line = std::string{};
while (std::getline(wtfile, line)) {
    auto iss = std::stringstream{line};
    // Third line of parameters are the convolution layer biases,
    // so this tells us the amount of channels in the residual layers.
    // We are assuming all layers have the same amount of filters.
    if (linecount == 2) {
        auto count = std::distance(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(iss),
                                   std::istream_iterator<std::string>());
        myprintf("%d channels...", count);
        channels = count;
    }
    linecount++;
}
```

Comment: It counts the number of strings in the stream.

Answer (score 0):

@n.m. I am not sure whay you did not put this into the answer box? With that and the filter "answers:0", everybody can still see this. So I will put it as answer, but all credential go to n.m.

In the C++ Algorithm and Itarator library, you can find many iterators and applications in conjunction with algorithms.

Iterators are for example used to iterate over a range of elements in a STL-container. Or as a return value for a algorithm. They behave somehow like pointers. So, if you have 2 `std::vectors` and you want to copy the data from vec1 to vec2 you can use:

`std::copy(vec1.begin(), vec1.end(), vec2.begin());`

If you would search something in a vector of int, then you would use

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>

constexpr size_t VectorSisze = 10U;

int main()
{
    // Define Vecor with VectorSisze elements
    std::vector<int> v(VectorSisze);
    // Fill the vector with consecutive numbers
    std::iota(v.begin(),v.end(),0);

    // Search for entry 
    int searchValue{5};
    std::vector<int>::iterator iterSearch = std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), searchValue);

    // check, if we could find something
    if (iterSearch != v.end()) {
        size_t position = std::distance(v.begin(), iterSearch);
        std::cout << "Value "  << searchValue << " found at position " << position << "\n";

    }
    return 0;
}
```

And please see in the above example that we use `std::distance` to calculate the distance between 2 ietarors.

Thsi should be some clear now.

The next topic is the `std::istream_iterator`. The `std::istream_iterator` has also a begin. That is the iterator, given with the type of what to read and as parameter, the stream from which to read.

In your example `std::istream_iterator<std::string>(iss)`, will start to read strings from iss. `std::istream_iterator<std::string>()` without the function parameter is the "end()" iterator. So, you can read something from a stream from the beginning to the end. See the following example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

constexpr size_t VectorSisze = 5U;

int main()
{
    // Define Vecor with VectorSisze elements
    std::vector<int> v(VectorSisze);
    // Read 5 int values
    std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), VectorSisze, v.begin());
    std::cout <<  "Second value: " << v[1] << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

And if you calculate the distance between the begin and the end, then you have the number of elements.

And because your iterator reads the `std::string`, you will have the number of strings in your stream